# didUpdateLocations is taking a long time to load

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Hello I'm currently developing an IOS Application that uses Mapkit. My app is currently using locationmanager to get user location and to setregion. Something weird that is happening right now is that the time it takes to animate to the setregion is different when i'm at different a location.

For example when i'm at school where cellular signals is weak. The time it takes for mapkit to set region is about 10x longer when i'm at home where the cellular signal is strong.

I'm currently using requestLocation() to call the didupdatelocation function and people on the web advice to use startUpdatingLocation. The thing about this is that i only want to setregion once in my app. While didupdatelocation is continuously doing it.

I'm kind of stuck and do not know where to start to solve this problem. Please help!

Comment: `requestLocation()` will wait up to 10 seconds to try and find a location that is as accurate as the `desiredAccuracy` you set on the location manager.  The time it takes to to call `didUpdateLocation` is however long it takes to get an accurate location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example when I'm at the school where cellular signals is weak. The time it takes for mapkit to set region is about 10x longer when i'm at home where the cellular signal is strong.

- This is an expected behavior. Retrieving location is a network intensive task however configure the [desiredAccuracy](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy?language=objc) and [distanceFilter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter?language=objc) properties of the location manager and then call the [requestLocation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation?language=objc) or [startUpdatingLocation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation?language=objc).
- Never specify an accuracy value greater than what you need. [Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager?language=objc) uses the accuracy value you specify to manage power better.
  A higher degree of accuracy requires more precise hardware like GPS, which consumes more power.

> The thing about this is that i only want to setregion once in my app.

- Passing a `nil` message to the `CLLocationManager` instance will prevent any successive `didUpdateLocation:` invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sense! and Sorry I'm a bit new to Swift but How would I pass a nil message to CLLocationManager? Thanks